# Custom javascript code using jQuery is not working Angular 5 (angular-cli)

Tags: jquery, angular-cli, angular5

I am building an application using Angular 5 with angular-cli. I've written custom functions using jquery and these functions are not working. Let me tell what I've done.

steps:

1. Have installed jquery using below commands

   npm install --save jquery
   npm install @types/jquery --save ( i know this is for intellisense in typescript)
2. Created a file main.js where i kept all of my custom functions
3. referred jquery in .angular-cli.json as below

   scripts:[
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
       "assets/js/main.js"
       ]

now the function below (i picked one of the functions) in main.js is not working.

```
$( '.search__open' ).on( 'click', function () {
    $( 'body' ).toggleClass( 'search__box__show__hide' );
    return false;
  });
```

the class  .search__box__show__hide has to be appended to body which is not happeing. I googled, been through many articles in stackoverflow and followed best suggestions to use external libraries such as jquery in angular-cli but no luck.

if I use the below code (which is part of above code fragment) in one of my component then it is working fine.

```
$( 'body' ).toggleClass( 'search__box__show__hide' );
```

which means $ is recognized from jquery but the same is not working from main.js file.

Please let me know what I've been doing wrong, your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed the steps outlined [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib)? The second half of this shows how to use libraries that have no typings. It may work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Richards.

I've followed the steps described in your provided link till adding types in typings.d.ts file and later steps explained how the library can be used in one of the .ts files. But my problem is that the code in my main.js(not a typescript) file is not working.

Comment: Have you thought about the idea of converting the main.js file to Typescript? I don't know if that would be difficult.

Comment: I am still hoping a resolution with main.js otherwise converting in to TS is my last resort.. :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem was all of htmls referred as templateUrls in component are rendered later the scripts referred using script tags are evaluated. The solution is, use 'defer' on script tag to make sure these scripts are evaluated after the page is loaded.

**Before:**

```
<html>
   ......
   <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
   </body>
<html>
```

**After:**

```
<html>
   ......
   <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
        <script src="main.js" defer></script>
   </body>
<html>
```

Comment: The correct fix would have been to load/bundle your dependencies with your ES Module tools (SystemJS/Webpack, etc.) instead of depending on script tag ordering and global variables. The entire purpose of ES Modules is to avoid the issues you experienced but instead you have the worst of all possible worlds, the most highest achievable complexity.